# http request protect from android

Tags: java, php, android

I have a script server side and print a json array, I would like prevent other apps can call this file.

I have some ideas but it don´t convince me at all:

1.- Use staic get token, but it´s not enough.

2.- Change token monthly, but I can lost old users who did not updated app.

3.- Detect the package name of the app and send a precall with some data to recognize my users.

Any idea how can I protect or difference my clients or user that have installed my app?

Greetens

Answer (score 1):

What if you encrypted the output of your script and built the decryption key into your android apps?  Then only your apps could use the output.  Other people could still call your script but the output would be useless.

Comment: I tought that too, but if I use AES_encrypt and decrypt I need to place in the android code the key for decryption too... hehe it´s a big problem. and decompilling the app you have everything... So make things harder but some other programmer can access this information too.

Comment: Are they likely to do that though?  And if a few succeed does it matter?  If so your going to be looking at a much more complex system along the lines of registering each app user.  You have to decide if this is worth the investment.

Comment: In this case is a big manually work (info) to protect, not personal information, but I would like to have it secured as possible, and make it complex if some other would access to my data.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you cannot distinguish bytes from your app, and identical ones from an adversary. If your app sends `0xDEADBEEF` then the adversary can do the same. Depending on how important security is you can try static tokens, AES encryption, manual obfuscation of token-determining logic, and even a tool like DexGuard (no affiliation) to limit decompilation to human-unreadable "junk" through which execution flow is nearly impossible to trace.

Comment: Hexafraction thanks for your reply what do you mean with DexGuard (no affiliation) ? exactly? Cheers

Comment: @David It means that I am referring to a program called DexGuard, but am stating that I did not write it, and therefore am not advertising my own work. It's actually a spin-off of ProGuard, which is more familiar to most people.

Comment: Do you have a website to see some info about your obfuscation script, please. Cheers and thanks both for your replies.

Comment: @David Once again, it is not my product. It seems that DexGuard is just a pro version of ProGuard, you could use Proguard for free to obfuscate jars, and then convert those to apks